# how to decode marshal.loads?

Tags: python, base64, decode, cracking

How to decode `marshal.loads` code ?
Is there any way to decode it to python code ?

```
marshal.loads(zlib.decompress(b'x\x9c\\WyT\x12\x88\xd7\x9d\xa6)\x7fM\x99\x99\x93Vn5\x9aN\xb9\x90c.\xb8\xc04N9\xe6VY\xb9kjI\xb9\x8b
```